# How to put the text of a textarea into a .txt file on the server that the html is on?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

**NEW SITUATION/QUESTION**

This is the same question, but I am trying it a different way. If you see what I did below and my comments with Rob, I was trying to do it with PHP, but I've spent the past few days trying to get PHP on my nginx server through Docker, and I've been having a really tough time.

So, I decided to go back to the initial problem (the question in the title). So, I tried to implement some other code online and something happens, but I just have a few questions about it. With this code:

```
    function textbox(){
        document.getElementById("textInput").className="show";
}

function WriteToFile(passForm) {
     var fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
     var s   = fso.CreateTextFile("/home/bsluss/b_test/CTO-Signing-Server/signing-server/www/cgi-bin/tmp.txt", True);

     var textinfo = document.getElementById('message');

     s.writeline(textinfo);
     s.close();
}

</script>

...

<input type="button" value="Add Cloud Info" onclick="textbox()" />
<div id="textInput" class="hide">
        <form id="form" class="topBefore" onSubmit="WriteToFile(this)">
  <textarea type="text" name="text" id="message" value=""></textarea><br>
  <input id="submit"  type ="submit" value="Copy to File"></input>
        </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

After typing in '1234' in the textarea and upon submit, it refreshed my page with the same url, but 'text=1234' was on the end. I'm just not sure where this txt document that I wanted to create is. It's not in the filepath that I specified in the WriteToFile function. I'm not sure if this is because I'm doing this on Docker, a virtual host server? Any help regarding this would be great!

**OLD SITUATION/QUESTION**

I have this server from an IP address. I have other buttons and such that will take me to other pages. I am trying to implement a textarea that will allow the user to paste text and then on a button click or 'submit' click will copy that text to a tmp txt file which I will run some pre-made scripts on. I'm having a really hard time figuring out not only how to pass this text to a new txt file, but also accessing it through the server (through PUTTY via the IP address). I believe I need to use PHP to do this, which I haven't used until today. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's what I have so far. This is all in the same index.html file. I tried creating a filename.php file and letting the action=filename.php, but was getting similar results and don't really understand the difference.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["text"])) {
  $txt = $_POST["text"];
  $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tmp/tmpdata.txt';
  $fp = fopen($file, "a+");
  fwrite($fp, $txt . PHP_EOL);
  fclose($fp);
  echo 'Success.';
} else{
  echo 'Error.';
}
?>

<html>
<body>

 <form id="form" class="topBefore" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>" method="POST">
  <textarea type="text" name="text" id="message" value=""></textarea><br>
  <input id="submit"  type ="submit" value="Copy to File"></input>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Upon clicking the submit button with this code, it brings me to a new page with error code 404 Page not Found. If I change the method to GET instead of POST, then it will download a txt file using the Notepad application (which is closer to what I want), but I cannot find this new file under the file tree on the server.

Comment: change to `action=""`

Answer (score 1):

The file extension should probly be .php, not .html, unless your server is configured to parse HTML as PHP, which I would recommend against. The action of the form can be empty, since you are submitting to the same file, so action="" as @LawrenceCherone mentioned in his comment.

Unless you really need the text file to be publicly available, best practice is to store it somewhere outside the document root. Since you mentioned accessing it via PUTTY, it sounds like that won't be a problem. Your code works, but I recommend adding some error checking at a minimum. The HTML also has some quirks I recommend ironing out. Here's a solid starting point.

```php
<?php
// Set up a status flag end message string
$status = 'init';
$msg = '';

// If the submit button was pressed, attempt to process the post
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    try
    {
        // Make sure we have text, if not, return an error
        if (empty($_POST["text"]))
        {
            throw new Exception('Please enter text');
        }

        $txt = $_POST["text"];

        /*
         * Path to the file - it's a good practice to place this outside the
         * document root so it's not publicly available or executable by the
         * server.
         */
        $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/tmp/tmpdata.txt';

        // Attempt to open a file handle, If we can't, bail out with an error
        if (($fp = fopen($file, "a+")) === false)
        {
            throw new Exception('Unable to open file for writing');
        }

        if(fwrite($fp, $txt . PHP_EOL) === false)
        {
            throw new Exception('Unable to write to file');
        }

        fclose($fp);

        // Set the status to success
        $status = 'success';
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        $status = 'error';
        $msg    = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<?php if ($status == 'error') { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-error"><?php echo $msg; ?></div>
<?php } elseif ($status == 'success') { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success">Text stored successfully</div>
<?php } ?>
<body>
<form id="form" class="topBefore" action="" method="POST">
    <textarea name="text" id="message"></textarea><br>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Copy to File">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if I create a .php file with just the php code in it and then have the action=filename.php, would it do the same thing?

Comment: Also, if the code works, how come I can't find the txt.file in the file tree?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, the filename will work like that. There could be any number of issues with the file creation that are not code-related, like missing tmp directory, file permissions, etc. That's why you need the error handling. If everything outside your current script is set up correctly, it will work. But if not, it will fail and you won't know why.

Comment: Hmm I haven't implemented your code because I'm still thinking about things. Both you and many other sources say my php code will not run in .html file, but I've also found that I cannot pass a variable from a php file to an html file (there is no submit button that uses form method=POST to pull the variables like you can going from html to php. So, the php code you have in the html file "if status=error...Text stored successfully." would that also go in the .php file? If so how does the html display the message "Text stored Successfully"? Thanks so much for your help

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about, there is no HTML file in this scenario. If this file is filename.php, the user requests filename.php, and since there is no submit parameter in the post superglobal array, it displays the blank form. The user then submits the form - which posts to the same file - and the parameter is present, so we perform the operation and display the resulting messages to the user. You may be overthinking this.

Comment: Ah, I was given this .html file that has all the code I posted in it. I'm not sure if changing this file to a .php file will mess up things elsewhere. I can try, but I was going to leave all the code (except php code) in this .html file. Then, having the <form action="otherfile.php"> which would jump to the php file and execute the php code including the <?php if ($status == 'error') { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-error"><?php echo $msg; ?></div>
<?php } elseif ($status == 'success') { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success">Text stored successfully</div>
<?php } ?>

Comment: That's really not a good idea. At best you end up with two versions of the HTML form to maintain, and there is no benefit. If you do keep an HTML file that submits to the PHP file, remove the PHP code from the HTML file or it will be sent to the browser along with the HTML, unless you server is configured to run HTML files through the PHP engine (which it should not be). I recommend you spend some time going through PHP tutorials so that you really understand how this works before putting things on your server that upload files. It's pretty easy to create a gaping security hole on your server.